# MS Exchange: How to categorize incoming emails in a shared mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

Here's the scenario:

We have an efax system setup and use Office 365. I created 3 shared mailboxes, and appropriately named them after their office locations, ex Office1@domain.com, Office2@domain.com, Office3@domain.com
The efax system sends emails with the faxes as an attachment to the appropriate shared mailbox, based on the phone number it was sent TO. faxes sent to 718-555-9999 get forwarded to Office2@domain.com

I have a staff of 25 users that I gave full access to all 3 shared mailboxes, so they can check all incoming faxes as needed. When an email comes in, the subject states the phone number the fax was sent FROM. Each staff member is responsible for receiving faxes from the same 3-5 phone numbers every week.

What I would like to accomplish is to use the Categorize feature in Outlook to automatically color code these emails. Each staff member would be assigned a color, and the name of the category would be renamed to the staff members name.

I already customized the categories, and renamed a bunch of colors to the staff name, and have the staff right click on emails that belong to them and add their color to it. This process is manual and done after the fact.

I would like to automate this process so these emails are color coded as soon as they come in.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, we can use Outlook rules.

Log on the shared mailbox and create a rule to automatically assign a color to messages from these faxes.

[image]

Please check whether this works.

Comment: This worked! Thank you
I did have to open the shared mailbox in owa and create the rules there
Now I wonder if these are considered client-side or server-side rules...

Comment: This rule is show as "server-side rule" on my account.

Comment: If the rule is client-side, you can see a message on OWA: "This rule is created using the desktop version of Outlook. You can't view and edit it".